# GlassFish WAR file deployment to a non-default port

Tags: deployment, glassfish, war

I am attempting to deploy a war file (Oracle's APEX Listener) to a GlassFish 3.1.2.2 server deployed on an RHEL server (I am also seeing the same issues on an Ubuntu server at home).

I used the following command to create the domain:

> $GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin create-domain --portbase 8100 myDomain

[I am also creating multiple domains on the same GlassFish server (one GF instance with multiple domains) using values of 8200, 8300, and 8400 for the portbase value and using different domain names.]

I then start the domain using:

> $GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin start-domain myDomain

Next, I attempt to deploy the APEX.WAR file using:

> $GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin deploy --contextroot apex apex.war

But, I get the following error:

> **Remote server does not listen for requests on [localhost:4848]. Is the server up? Unable to get remote commands.  Closest matching local
>   command(s): 
>       help Command deploy failed.**

I have also used the following commands with the same result:

> $GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin deploy apex.war
>   $GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin deploy --target myDomain apex.war
>   $GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin deploy --target domain apex.war

And I get the same error each time.

I can deploy the file using the admin gui, but this is for a customer installation and I would really like to do as much as possible from the bash shell script I have created.

I am also installing the Java 1.7.0_45 JDK and modifying the $GLASSFISH_HOME/config/asenv.conf file to include AS_JAVA=

The error is actually correct because the admin port is 8148. But, how do I get GlassFish to "know" to use 8148 instead of 4848.

I have also tried this by:

> $GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin create-domain --adminport 8148
>   --domainproperties http.ssl.port=8152

but this gets the same results as above.

Thanks for reading this tome of a post and any info on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

/dave

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the port to which `asadmin` should connect as a parameter like this:

```
asadmin --port 4949 start-domain
```

If this isn't enough you can even specify the hostname with `--host`.

Have a look at the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/asadmin-1m.html) to see all possible parameters.

Answer (score 0):

i get the same error ,you should do like this:

$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin --port 8148  deploy apex.war

and input username and password the default user is admin and password is adminadmin

good luck for you!